как записать результат цикла for в .txt (функция re match)
Дана функция for , которая может выдать несколько значений - все индексы некоторой последовательности в большей последовательности:
for match in re.finditer('aaaacttaataaaattaa',datat):
        useless = (match.start(), match.end())
        print(useless)

Когда я пытаюсь записать результат вместе с другими важными мне результатами в файл txt, записывается только последнее значение useless:
name = 'Culex pipiens pipiens'
res = [name, N, d, rr, useless]

with open("Result_Culex.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in res:
        f.write(str(i) + ';' )
f.close()

Если важно, N, d, rr int формата, useless tuple

Если вам нужны все значения useless из первого цикла, то до цикла создайте переменную с пустым списком, в цикле значения в этот список добавляйте. Во втором фрагменте кода не добавляйте это в список res, а отдельным циклом выводите этот список в файл.

Спасибо большое, всё получилось!
